# How can I authenticate an MVC 5 application with IdentityServer4

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver4

My API Resource is an MVC 5 application.
In the Quickstart I got how to authenticate a .net core API Resource with Identityserver4 by adding dependency injection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:59392/";
                options.ApiName = "dataEventRecords";
                options.ApiSecret = "dataEventRecordsSecret";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });
}
```

Comment: Side note: Looks like you have extra parenthesis in your code.

Comment: not sure what is the question here?